# Get bitmap of an web page using WebBrowser Control in .net compact framework

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am trying out to get the bitmap of web page loaded in web browser control, but found that WebBrowser.CreateGraphics() and even WM_PRINT (DrawToBitmap) message response is also missing in .net compact framework.

After searching through internet found one of the .net sample code which gets complete web page in bitmap

When i tried porting it through compact framework for windows mobile 6.0 found that most of the API and methods missing.

How should i go ahead with it...

Any help in this regard will greatly appreciated.
Thanks- Ramanand Bhat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to take a snapshot of a web page via an asp.net application. I guess parts of that exercise would be useful to you.

You'd be interested in these 2 links:

http://69.10.233.10/KB/cs/webpage_thumbnailer.aspx
http://deostroll.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!428DAD5E3A907C31!181.entry

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for replay, 

But it only works for Desktop not for windows mobile with compact framework, do you have any idea to achieve same in windows mobile.

Thanks in advance.
Ramanand.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way is to just [take a full screen capture](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/03/11/ScreenCaptureInTheCompactFramework.aspx), then clip the result down to the bounds of the browser control.

Comment: Your answer was useful, but my web browser will be showing part of web page, we wanted to get the screen shoot of an entire web page which is hidden. 

Desktop web page capturing API's and functionality is totally missing in compact framework and mobile SDK, now i don't get any idea how to proceed.

Regards,
Ramanand Bhat.